# post is not taking params with it. JQuery post

Tags: jquery, post, parameters

So with other functions I have on the page I am able to post useing JQuery's $.post. For some reason I can not get this post to send over its parameters. Any idea why?

```
$(".changeStatus").on("click", function changeStatus(){
                var permissionName  =   $(this).parent().children('.permissionName').val();
                var empId           =   $(this).parent().children('.empId').val();
                var permissionLevel =   Number(($(this).parent().children('.permissionLevel').val())+1);

                if(permissionLevel > 3){permissionLevel = 0;}

                $.post("humanResourceFunctions.php/",
                {
                    command:"changePermissionStatus"
                },
                function(data, status){
                    alert(data);
                });
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how do you know it's not getting over there?

Comment: I am echoing out $_POST["command"]. Nothing is returned.

Comment: do you have chrome or firefox w/firebug? have you checked the network tab > headers > parameters?

Comment: I am receiving a status of 302 while the others are 200. Found that information in the network. Chrome

Comment: check the one with `humanResourceFunctions.php/` <-- if that is the correct address - click on it - go to headers - inside there check params - if they show up there they are getting sent

Comment: They are being sent. This is what I am receiving: command:changePermissionStatus
employeeId:"8"
permName:"residentMap"
permLevel:"1" Just added in my other fields to test out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your server returns a 301 or 302 response code if it does then the ajax data is lost due to the redirect (security issue).

"301 Redirects lose contents of the POST. So jQuery is sending it along, but the server redirects it to the right location of the script without the POST data. You need to figure out where the right location of the script is and specify that in your jquery call to avoid the redirect"

Comment: Yep, I am getting a 302 message. Any thoughts on why my other $.posts are getting through but this one is not? They all reside on the same page. In fact this one is right under one that is working just fine.

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash from the script location ( browsers may redirect you ), check if you set the redirect header in php or check the htaccess file for the redirects.

Comment: I guess we don't know whether the server is supposed to 302 this request given the parameter values and the URL. Perhaps its supposed to and the params get lost on the redirect. Perhaps its a problem with the parameters and the redirect is to an error page or login or similar.

Comment: Probably not the case since he stated he is just checking the post data in that script and no error handling were performed

Comment: Echoing before or after the script finds a problem or some filter-like thing before the script gets it.

Comment: This solved my problem. What was going on was that I had a redirect in php file that the ajax was calling. After removing that, Post works just fine. Thank you to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

**Ignore this answer** It just reflects the question not having all the parameers shown as the code was pared down for SO. The only reason I didn't delete it is that the comments seemed interesting at the time.

---

Perhaps you need to put more parameters in the post:

```
$.post("humanResourceFunctions.php/",
     {
         command:"changePermissionStatus",
         empId: empId,
         ... all the others
     },
     function(data, status){
         alert(data);
     }
);
```

Comment: This is what it will have and it still does not take. employeeId: '"'+empId+'"',
      permName:'"'+permissionName+'"',
      permLevel:'"'+permissionLevel+'"'

Comment: Why the double quotes and plus sign stuff?

Comment: Concatenating my variables.

Comment: Why with empty strings?

Comment: Bad codeing on my part. Fixed to now look like $.post("humanResourceFunctions.php/",
     {
      command:"changePermissionStatus",
      employeeId: empId,
      permName: permissionName,
      permLevel: permissionLevel
     },
     function(data, status){
      alert(data);
     }); But I still have the same problem.